# Get history of IP configuration changes

Tags: windows-7, event-log, ipconfig

I have monitored some problems with the IP configuration during job execution. It looks like the DNS server name and the domain suffix is changed sometimes.

I would like to find corresponding events in the event log. For this purpose I want to know: How can I identify the point of time when the IP configuration change occurred?

**Edit**:
The question has been marked as duplicated. The referred question handle the IP history of the PC. But none of these other questions (and answer) touch the important detail:

> What DNS server address has been assigned at what time?

Therefore I voted to reopen my question.

Anyway, I followed the tips to extend the logging with event log. No events of DHCP result changes have been logged, although the DNS lookup changed after some days.

**Edit:**
I did not found an answer to question. But the reason for the DNS change was an additional router that should provide access to a WLAN. Accidentally the DHCP server of that router was enabled and gave the wrong DNS server address.

Comment: Go to Event Viewer->Applications and Services Logs->Microsoft->Windows->Dhcp-Client->Microsoft-Windows-DHCP Client Events/Operational. Look at the option under "Properties" in the Actions column on the right. If it is "Disable Log", you have enabled this log, then you can view the past IP. If it is "Enable Log", you have not enabled this log and the previous IP cannot be viewed.

Comment: @S.Leon: Why are you posting that as a comment?

Comment: @grawity Some people have different opinions about whether this method is feasible. And I did not test to verify this method. So I just post it in the comment as a suggestion, in case I may mislead others if it doesn't work.

Comment: @S.Leon That's what answers and moderation are for- letting users know if something works or not. Posting an answer as a comment 'in case it doesn't work' is not the right use of comments.